# How to switch to administrator Win Vista Ultimate

Tags: windows-vista

I have Windows Vista Ultimate installed on my PC, and when I boot , and the login screen appears, how do I switch to administrator login, at the moment it's only one username that appears and I need to use the administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/08/10/activate-enable-and-show-administrator-account-in-vista-welcome-screen/) that tells you how you can do this. Here are the full isntructions for doing this, from mydigitallife.info:

- Logon to Windows Vista with normal user account username and password (must belongs to Administrators group).
- Click on Vista Start button, and type `cmd` in the Start Search box.
- Right click on the Cmd returned on the search results pane above, then select **Run as Administrator**.
- In the Command Prompt window, type the following text at the command line to set a password for administrator account: `net user administrator password`. If you want to use a blank password for the Administrator account, skip this step. Replace password with the actual password string that you have chosen. Press **Enter** when done. Note that if your computer is a member of domain controller or has enabled complex password requirement in Local Security Policy, you will have to pick a really hard to remember password mixed with symbols.
- Next type the following command and press **Enter** to activate and enable Administrator account: `net user administrator activate:yes`. The process should complete with the following message: *The command completed successfully*.
- Logout from Vista by choosing **Log Off** or **Switch User**.
- Click on Administrator icon and logon with the password you selected.

Comment: Thx, And if I can't remember the password for the other account

Comment: Glad I could help!